# How to view/open PowerScript file without PowerBuilder

Tags: powerbuilder

I've got a PowerBuilder project that I want to inspect 
but I don't have PowerBuilder installed .
I tried PB Peeper but it freezes when I try to browse through pbl files.
Does anyone know any sort of software that I can open and see the source Powerscript with ?
Thank you

Comment: New version of PBL Peeper (4.1.3) has been posted. If that doesn't work for you, there's an email address at the top of the Feedback page (the form doesn't work) that will probably get you a fix (if your issue isn't a corrupt PBL).

Comment: Thank your for the update. I'll definitely give another go for it : )

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the most simple I know is pbdumper (http://sebastien.kirche.free.fr/powerbuilder/en.html ) so you can extract source code as *.sr? files and view with any text editor.

Answer (score 4):

Try  [yBrowser](https://web.archive.org/web/20130718160048/http://www.ybrowser.com/), it is really good.

- Freeware
- No PowerBuilder installation required
- Various browsing and searching features

Comment: Thank you! This one also seems nice ! I would have chosen your answer too if I were allowed to choose more than one answer : )